# Paho publishing stops after first topic on Docker

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

My code publishes to a list of topics at a specific time. I run this locally and it sometimes doesnt react as it should. Once I dockerize it it only publishes to the first topic. Any help would be appreciated

```
def connector():
    port = 1833
    msg = {'state': "off"}
    client1 = paho.Client("shutdown_client")
    client1.on_publish = on_publish
    client1.connect(brok, port=1883)
    sleep(5)
    print("connected")
    for topic in sub:
       ret = client1.publish(topic, orjson.dumps(msg))

def on_publish(client, userdata, result):
    print("shutting down office:", result)
    pass

 
def main():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.start()
    print(scheduler)
    trigger = CronTrigger(
        year="*", month="*", day="*", hour="*", minute="*", second="00"
    , timezone='Europe/Amsterdam')
    scheduler.add_job(
        connector,
        trigger=trigger,
        name="daily shutdown",
    )
    while True:
        sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not started the Paho's client [network loop](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#network-loop), without it won't send messages larger than the MTU of the network.

You also appear to never shut the client down so it will leak clients every time it runs.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. So I should `loop.start()` before the `for` loop and loop end right after like they show explain in the `While` loop example?

Comment: That would be a start, but you also need to disconnect the client when done with it, else you will just leak clients as I said.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, ill look into the `publish.multiple` module since it appears to disconnect cleanly after publishing. Which fits my code perfectly. Again thanks for answering.